# Angular 4 - Bind jQuery event (click) after *ngfor created dynamic components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

I have a situation whereby the below code in my viewasd

```
    <div class="item" *ngFor="let property of propertiesRecent; let i=index">
       <app-property [property]="property" (propertyCreated)="onPropertyCreated()"></app-property></div>
```

Now app-property looks something like this:

```
 <span class="col-lg-2 socialShare">
<fa name="share-alt" size="3"></fa>
</span>
```

I want to bind a jquery event on the above but once the DOM has updated after the value of propertiesRecent is updated I loose the jquery click event listner..

```
$('.socialShareIcons').hide()
```

How I do this? If you check the ngFor I tried custom event, I tried AfterViewChecked both in app-property component but did not help...

Comment: Why are you using Jquery here? Need to know more details about this question.

Comment: What element has the `socialShareIcons` class? Why not use angular events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a similar problem, Here is a [link](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8663#issuecomment-318810576) on github with provided solution and respective discussion

In short:

```
<div #label *ngFor="...

Component:
Class SuperComponent {
ViewChild('label')
public label: any;
...
ngAfterViewInit() {
this.handleEndOfNgfor();
this.label.changes.subscribe(()=>this.handleEndOfNgfor());
}
private handleEndOfNgfor() 
console.log('hooray!');
}
}
```